# How can I make an object face towards a position in Roblox Studio?

Tags: lua, rotation, roblox

I've been trying to get a part, to change rotation to point toward a specified point. Can't find anything googling, so I tried to make it myself.

I tried this: but instead of rotating anything, looks like the rotation just has the regular CFrame  functions, and just teleports it to the position.

```
if (pos ~= nil) then
    script.Parent.CFrame = script.Parent.CFrame.Rotation:ToWorldSpace(pos)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In Roblox's documentation, [Understanding CFrames](https://create.roblox.com/docs/building-and-visuals/studio-modeling/cframes#facing-toward-a-point), there's a section on rotating to face a point.

Essentially, one of the [CFrame constructors](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/datatypes/CFrame#new) allows you to pass in two Vector3s. The first is the object's position, and the second is the point to look at. So just use the object's current position for the first value, and the target position as the second value.

```lua
if (pos ~= nil) then
    local object = script.Parent
    local position = object.Position
    local look = pos

    object.CFrame = CFrame.new(position, look)
end
```